# How to Display the Text contents of pdf in yii / php?

Tags: php, yii

I want to display the text content of pdf in yii/php, Currently Iam using

```
$file=readfile('test.pdf');
echo $file;
```

By using this Iam getting the Pdf File in Binary Format as shown in the figure ,I want the output in Text Format ,How to achieve it? Thanks in Advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though not Yii specific you need to make sure you are setting the application/pdf content type when attempting to display a PDF file in a browser.

As such:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
$file = readfile('./pdf.pdf');

echo $file;

?>
```

Comment: Ya I have tried it But my File Contents looks in binary format as i mentioned in the Figure.Is there any other solution?

Comment: So you **ARE** using `header("Content-type: applicationg/pdf");`?

If so then also try: `header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="pdf.pdf"');`